# What are some proofs for which dramatically shorter alternatives were later published?

Tags: math-history

Sometimes a mathematical result is initially proved with a very long and convoluted argument, but later after the proof and truth is well-understood, a better, simpler proof of the same result will become apparent.

Are there any examples of problems which had huge first-proofs, but later insight yielded extremely short and elegant proofs?

Comment: It would make more sense to ask for proofs that have not been simplified over the years.

Answer (score 1):

[**Irrationality of $\pi$**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational)

The proof given by [Lambert](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895611/lamberts-original-proof-that-pi-is-irrational) is long but [Niven's proof](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-06/S0002-9904-1947-08821-2/S0002-9904-1947-08821-2.pdf) is just a paragraph long.

Comment: This was debated over at MO https://mathoverflow.net/a/43947/112504